# Effect on Linux of usage of custom TTF font

Tags: css, linux, macos, browser, truetype

I am developing a Wicket Application, where I am using a custom ttf font. I have placed the font copied from my Windows 7 in the war and have used in css as:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Kunstler;
    src: url('fonts/KUNSTLER.TTF');
}
```

and then:

```
.parent p {
    font-family: Kunstler;
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

Since I am running the application from locally. I cannot see whether or not it is working in Linux or Mac.

I don't know the mechanism, that how the browser renders font.

My question is:

- Is it safe to use font this way?
- Will this work in all kind of machine(Linux, Windows, Mac)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "[browsershots](http://browsershots.org/)", to see how the page looks (it supports lot's of browsers and operating systems), just make the website visible for it and it will render the webpage fo you.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to find out would be to set up a popular Linux distribution in a virtual machine running atop your windows installation, or boot off of a liveCD or installer with a "try it without installing" mode.

But do you have a license to distribute that font?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So there is no other way or information from prior experience! Yes I do have the license.